# Winding losses in transformer

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply

Here is the following assertions from "Section 4 – Power Transformer Design" written by TI (https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slup126/slup126.pdf) :

[image]

From the Faraday's Law, the current across the primary winding or the primary inductance is proportionnal to the duty cycle and Vin (volt-seconds product) and is inversely proportionnal to the switching frequency (and the inductance). Nevertheless, it is true by experience that the primary current is higher when Vin is low... It implies that the volt second product is higher at low Vin... I have some troubles to find the physical relation that prove it ! Could you please help me ?

Thank you and have a nice day :)

Comment: A link to the TI document will probably help.

Comment: Doesn't it simply mean that the volt-second product is constant, so the seconds (duty cycle) increase as Vin reduces? What does that do to I (and I^2*R)?

Comment: I m trying to understand how the winding losses are affected in function of the different parameters of a forward converter for example. (Without considering proximity and skin effect at this point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Nevertheless, it is true by experience that the primary current is
>   higher when Vin is low... It implies that the volt second product is
>   higher at low Vin... I have some troubles to find the physical
>   relation that prove it !*

Firstly, TI is talking about a regulator and secondly they are referring to (mainly) the primary current that flows due to the secondary load so, talking about volt.seconds is somewhat missing the point. The primary current is higher when \$V_{IN}\$ is lower because the "regulation controller" will increase the duty cycle to ensure the output voltage remains regulated.

It's not 100% like in a flyback converter where increasing the duty cycle (to accommodate a greater load current or lower \$V_{IN}\$) will have a volt.second (and core saturation) implications. The article (at that point) is talking about primary referred load currents.

For a forward converter increasing the duty cycle applies more energy to the load. Yes, there will be a volt.second implication for the magnetization current but this will be much smaller than the implication for a flyback converter.

And, as the article says, winding losses will be greater at lower values of \$V_{IN}\$ - this is because the primary current is greater in order to supply the load with a regulated voltage.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I m sorry for the missing points that I forgot to mention. I do not understand " The primary current is higher when VIN is lower because the "regulation controller" will increase the duty cycle to ensure the output voltage remains regulated." According to Faraday's Law, the output voltage is regulated via the magnetic flux generated at the primary. If the output voltage is constant, it implies a average flux is constant into the transformer. The flux into the transformer is proportionnal to the volt second product at the primary.

Comment: So if you change the volt seconds product, you change the output voltage ? No ? Where is my error ? What you say is we increase the duty cycle when Vin is lower. I agree with you but the volt second product is not changed. And the primary current is the same... ? I m missing something ... :(

Comment: I have assumed it is a buck regulating forward converter and it is the inductor on the output secondary that handles the energy storage and release into the load. The transformer is just used as a transformer to pass a varying duty cycle to the secondary inductor. If I have gotten the wrong end of the stick please show a schematic of what you assume to be correct.

Comment: I do not know what is the answer.... I will try to look for it !